pg_dump Issue While Exporting Schema of Existing Postgres Database for YugaByte Migration
I have an existing postgres database which I want to migrate to YugaByte using yb-voyager. I used the below command to export the postgres database schema.
yb-voyager export schema --export-dir <EXPORT_DIR> \
        --source-db-type <SOURCE_DB_TYPE> \
        --source-db-host <SOURCE_DB_HOST> \
        --source-db-user <SOURCE_DB_USER> \
        --source-db-password <SOURCE_DB_PASSWORD> \
        --source-db-name <SOURCE_DB_NAME> \
        --source-db-schema <SOURCE_DB_SCHEMA>

However, I get below error with pg_dump.

What should I do in this case?

The error is pretty straight forward,  pg_dump version 14+ is not in your $PATH. Make sure you have that version on the machine and get it in your $PATH

I checked that the version of pg_dump (PostgreSQL) is 10.23 whereas postgresql is 12.16. I do not want to upgrade postgresql. Is it possible to update only pg_dump such as 14.0 version? Which $PATH variable are you referring to?


The issue seems to be with yb-voyager, it it looking for pg_dump and pg_restore >= 14.0 and psql >= 9.0.  You will probably need to bring that up with them. 2) $PATH would be the path setting in whatever shell you are using on whatever OS you are using, neither of which you have included in the question.


I found that I have multiple version of pg_dump installed.

So, I linked the newer version using the below command:
sudo ln -sfn /usr/pgsql-14/bin/pg_dump /usr/bin/pg_dump

